# How can I help the poster of this question which I don't believe to be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, specific-question, closed-questions

[How to adapt a string splitting algorithm using pointers so it uses iterators instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629158/function-to-split-string-by-commas-and-return-as-vector) was asked yesterday, and almost immediately flagged as a possible duplicate of [Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens, e.g. ";"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g). However, the OP clearly links to an answer for a different string tokenizing question ([How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)) in their post.

The question is *not* about how to tokenize a string, it's about how to turn an algorithm written in terms of pointers into one using C++ (string) iterators. There are a bunch of questions relating to the differences between pointers and iterators, how to use iterators, etc. but I haven't found any that fit exactly.

I flagged the question for moderator attention, because I think it should be edited and re-opened. What other steps should I take?

- I could edit the post myself, and hope that somebody re-opens it so that I (and others) can post an answer. Note that I do not have sufficient reputation to cast a reopen vote myself.
- I can post an answer as a comment, although that's not really what comments are for.
- I can hope the OP got enough from my earlier comments about iterators that they figured it out, although that may not be as much help to subsequent visitors to that question.
- I can ignore it, but that doesn't help anyone.

---

For reference, I'd propose the question be edited to make it clear that the OP is asking about how to use iterators (or something else provided by `std::string`) to implement the same algorithm as the pointer-based example. It might look something like:

> The code below is taken from an answer to [this question on string
>   splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top).
>   It uses pointers, and a comment on that thread mentioned it could be
>   adapted for `std::string`. How can I use the features of `std::string`
>   to implement the same algorithm, for example using iterators?
>
> ```cpp
> #include <vector>
> #include <string>
> using namespace std;
>
> vector<string> split(const char *str, char c = ',')
> {
>     vector<string> result;
>
>     do
>     {
>         const char *begin = str;
>
>         while(*str != c && *str)
>           str++;
>
>         result.push_back(string(begin, str));
>     } while (0 != *str++);
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```
>
> I can pass a string into the function, but how do I get a pointer (or iterator) to the first character, and how do my loop termination criteria change?

---

An answer would probably look something like:

> You can use [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)
>   instead of pointers. Iterators provide a way to traverse containers,
>   and can usually be thought of as analogous to pointers.
>
> In this case, you can use the `begin()` member function (or `cbegin()`
>   if you don't need to modify the elements) of a `std::string` object to
>   obtain an iterator that references the first character, and the
>   `end()` (or `cend()`) member function to obtain an iterator for
>   "one-past-the-end".
>
> For the inner loop, your termination criterion is the same; you want
>   to stop when you hit the delimiter on which you'll be splitting the
>   string. For the outer loop, instead of comparing the character value
>   against `'\0'`, you can compare the iterator against the end iterator
>   you already obtained from the `end()` member function. The rest of the
>   algorithm is pretty similar; iterators work like pointers in terms of
>   dereference and increment:
>
> ```cpp
> std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, const char delim = ',') {
>     std::vector<std::string> result;
>
>     auto end = str.cend();
>     auto iter = str.cbegin();
>
>     do {
>         auto begin = iter;
>
>         while (iter != end && *iter != delim) ++iter;
>
>         result.push_back(std::string(begin, iter));
>     } while (iter++ != end);
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```
>
> Note the subtle difference in the iner loop condition: it now tests
>   whether we've hit the end *before* trying to dereference. This is
>   because we can't dereference an iterator that points to the end of a
>   container, so we must check this before trying to dereference. The
>   original algorithm assumes that a null character ends the string, so
>   we're ok to dereference a pointer to that position.

Note that this answer does not explain how to split a string, it explains how to adapt an existing algorithm to work with (string) iterators, highlighting a couple of important differences along the way.

Comment: @resueman not sure about that duplicate.  On the surface yes it asks the same general question, but this question does indicate that the question is unclear and needs to be edited first.  Similarly, since the OP here doesn't have 3K rep, the answer there is worthless as their is no "reopen flag".

Comment: You are welcome to ping me for reopening after the question is edited for clarity.

Comment: I've submitted an edit for the question. Thanks for clarifying the procedure here; I wasn't sure whether editing a closed post would be a waste of time. It's good to see that the system is designed to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: Well, it's reopened now. You might be interested in a question I just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657050/are-end1-iterators-for-stdstring-allowed, as you are potentially creating an end+1-iterator.

Comment: The first step is to edit is so it gets a good title; the title should focus on the question at hand, and not describe the context. If the question is about converting from pointer to iterator, then the title should mention it :x I took it upon myself to edit it for now, if anyone has better ideas please go ahead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes, I noticed this morning that I forgot to edit the title as well as the post body. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you see that people (understandably or not) mis-understand a question, you are encouraged to do a clarifying edit.
Just be aware that while we *want* edits which turn an unclear post drowning in irrelevancies and rambling into a concise and well-written one, the bigger the edit-distance the more crucial the edit-summary, and in special cases you might even want to ask in chat to avoid the robo-reviewers.

Your edit, once accepted, will place the question in the reopen-queue, and if you made things clear that should suffice (You might even ping the closer in this case, as he had a binding vote, but first do the edit and don't be obnoxious about it). It is obviously not a case for diamond-moderator intervention, as the community can handle it easily.

Comment: One note: One can only ping (@reply) a close-voter if the voter had a binding close vote (diamond or gold). See [#6](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236878/266187). Pinging any other close voter might become awkward by going to their and writing a comment on an unrelated post.

Comment: Yes, added a clarifiaction why it works in this case.

Comment: "Your edit, once accepted, will place the question in the reopen-queue, and if you made things clear that should suffice" It should suffice, but often it doesn't. Some people seem to love to plow through clicking 'leave closed' on everything (maybe because that is the quicker option?) to grind steward badges or do their review quota for the day, and because they're so fast, they do more reviews than the good reviewers who read things carefully. And the system is wired up so that it takes only 3 'leave closed' votes to leave a question closed, but up to 5 reopen votes to get it open again.

Comment: @Boann: Yes, those seeing the review-queues as a race instead of a way to help in moderation are a scourge. Trouble is, lots of edits are insufficient to justify reopening. But the votes weights aren't nearly as lop-sided as you make it sound: It needs a minimum of 1 reopen-vote (dupe-hammer, votes from outside the queues, votes from previous failed reopen-reviews) or 3 leave-closed votes to finish a reopen-review, and the reopen-votes might slowly age away, but they are sticky.