# What am I supposed to do if I think a question was closed incorrectly?

Tags: discussion

The other day I came across this question: [makefile error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38033151/453273). This question has some issues, to be sure. However, while I was attempting to figure out how to fix it, a user with a golden `c++` badge (the question has since been retagged as `c`) closed the question as a duplicate of this question: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I felt that closing as a duplicate of that question was a mistake. This question was really "why is my makefile not running the command line that I wrote in it", not "what is this linker error". I flagged the question as "in need of moderator intervention" and expressed this concern. That flag was declined because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". However, the question was subsequently migrated to the `c` tag and reopened by a gold-badge `c` user.

Did I flag the question inappropriately? If so, what should I have done? If not, why was my flag declined?

**Edit:** I don't think that this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258478/question-incorrectly-closed-as-duplicate) because the resolution to that question was "cast a re-open vote". Is that the only course of action available? I don't have enough rep to cast re-open votes. Is the question asker just out of luck?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309991/2301450) may be useful as well

Comment: It is open _for now_. It has 4 close votes sitting on it. (Off Topic-> Typo/unreproducable)

Comment: @theB True. I'm not really debating that it deserves to be open, just that if it should be closed, it should be closed for a different reason.

Comment: @vaultah That is definitely helpful! Am I to understand that editing any closed question will put it in the reopen queue?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel: no, [as far as I can tell](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/2301450)

Comment: @vaultah Thank you, this is exactly the information I was looking for.